# c# error: Input string not in correct format

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagrid view which is editable. I'm getting the value of a cell and then calculate the value of another cell. To do this I have handled CellEndEdit and CellBeginEdit events.

```
quantity = 0, quantity1 = 0, quantity_wt1 = 0, quantity_wt = 0, ekundag = 0;
private void grdCaret_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string value = grdCaret.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
        {
            int val = int.Parse(value);
            quantity = val;
            ekundag = ekundag + quantity;
            tbTotDag_cr.Text = ekundag.ToString();
        }

        if (e.ColumnIndex == 2)
        {
            float val = float.Parse(value);
            total = val;
            ekunrakam = ekunrakam + total;
            tbTotPrice_cr.Text = ekunrakam.ToString();
        }
        grdCaret.Columns[3].ReadOnly = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}

private void grdCaret_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    rate = 0;
    quantity1 = quantity;
    total1 = total;
    rate = (total1 / quantity1);
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 3)
    {
        grdCaret.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = rate.ToString();
        grdCaret.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ReadOnly = true;
        //  quantity = 0;
        //   total = 0;
    }
}
```

In the grid I have columns as quantity, total and rate. I get the above error here:

```
if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
{
    int val = int.Parse(value);
    quantity = val;
    ekundag = ekundag + quantity;
    tbTotDag_cr.Text = ekundag.ToString();
}
```

When I enter quantity and click on the total column in gridview. Please help me fix this

Comment: Have you used the debugger to see what `value`it is?

Comment: Fine, it would have been helpful to see that value then. You now have 5 people/answers that guessed what value it is.

Comment: It parses the value properly but gives me exception when i set that value to textbox. It evn tried to show that value in message box. I shows me properly but fails to set it to textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the int.Parse() function can possibly cause this kind of exceptions.

Have you tried to check the value in the cell? Isn't it possible, that some other characters are in the cell, not only the numbers? White spaces for example.

Comment: it gives me proper value in 'val' but it fails while setting the value to textbox

Answer (score 0):

The value you have entered into your Cell can't be parsed as Integer, so it will fail @
int val = int.Parse(value);

Answer (score 0):

try using `Text` instead of `ToString()`

```
string value = grdCaret.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.Text;
```

in place of

```
 string value = grdCaret.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input string 'value' is not in a valid format to be parsed to an integer. Take a look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32885/Difference-Between-Int32-Parse-Convert-ToInt32-and